# ¿Cómo puedo poner una condición en una función reduce en neo4j?

Tags: base-de-datos, neo4j

Estoy teniendo un problema en una consulta de neo4j y es que no sé cómo podría poner una condición en una sentencia reduce.
La consulta es esta:

```
MATCH p =
(a:Station{name:"Madrid"})-[r:connect*]-(b:Station{name:"Valladolid"})
WHERE all (n IN relationships(p) WHERE n.tipo="SC" or n.tipo="CC") 
RETURN reduce(totalDistance = 0.0, n in relationships(p) |
totalDistance + n.length) as reduction order by reduction
```

Y esta consulta funciona, pero lo que intento es algo como esto:

```
MATCH p =
(a:Station{name:"Madrid"})-[r:connect*]-(b:Station{name:"Valladolid"})
WHERE all (n IN relationships(p) WHERE n.tipo="SC" or n.tipo="CC") 
 RETURN reduce(totalDistance = 0.0, n in relationships(p) | **if n.type="SC"(
 totalDistance + (n.length*2)) else (totalDistance + (n.length*5))**) as reduction order by reduction
```

¿Hay alguna opción de hacer esto que digo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He descubierto que tengo que usar **CASE WHEN** dentro de la función reduce.
Quedaría algo como esto:

```
MATCH p = 
(a:Station{name:"Madrid"})-
[r:connect*]
 (b:Station{
 name:"Valladolid"})
 WHERE all (n IN 
 relationships(p) 
 WHERE n.tipo="SC" or 
 n.tipo="CC")
 RETURN reduce
 (totalDistance 
 = 0.0, n in 
 relationships(p) | 
 **case when n.type = "SC" 
 then totalDistance + 
 (n.length* 2) else 
 totalDistance + (n.length* 
 5) end**) as reduction 
  order by reduction
```

Espero que ayude a alguien más en el futuro que tenga el mismo problema